# Stationarity ⇒ homoscedasticity?

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, stationarity, univariate

If my data is stationary, can I also write that it is homoscedastic? Does stationarity imply homoscedasticity of the data?

Comment: Even weak stationarity implies constancy of variance in time or in whatever space a process is defined. I guess that in principle that need not rule out heteroscedasticity in some other respect. Counter-examples would be interesting.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the usage of the term *homoscedasticity,* but according to my understanding is mainly useful for time series which can be decomposed into an underlying signal and measurement noise. The concept of stationarity on the other hand can be also applied to deterministic processes: For example, a time series created by a chaotic logistic map is stationary but it isn’t anymore if I slightly let the parameter vary over time (in a deterministic fashion). I would not even know how to apply the concept of homoscedasticity to these time series, as they are both deterministic.

Comment: Homoscedasticity merely implies equal variance of a target variable across some index. For cross section data the index of interest is usually the regressor (i.e. does Y have the same variable for all levels of X?). For time series data the analogous index is time (t). In short, stationarity is a subset of the larger property of homoskedasticity, so yes.